# why does it cause error when trying to give the original pointer value a new value?

Tags: c, pointers

I am a newbie to C language, I am trying to use pointers as below.

1. `po1` is defined as a pointer which is pointing at an address. The PC allocates 1 byte of memory for it. `po2` is the same. I want to get the address of the memory pointed by `po2`, but only get an unexpected `0`, obviously not the address.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       char *po2, *po1;
       printf("---%d---\n", po2); 
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Output is:

   > demo11.c:5:23: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type >'char *' [-Wformat]
   >          printf("-****--%d-****--\n", po2); 
   >                     ~~        ^~~
   >                     %s
   >   1 warning generated.
   >   -****--0-****--
2. Then I am trying to give the value of `foo` to the memory `po2` is pointing at, but it gives an error.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       char *po2, *po1;
       char foo = 'D';
       *po2 = foo;
       printf("%c---------------\n", *po2); 
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Output is:

   > Terminated due to signal: SEGMENTATION FAULT (11)

Obviously, the error is caused by statement `*po2 = foo`;

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use %p to print pointer address values

Comment: @ttdado `because both pointer po1 and po2 are NULL` should be noted that this is only implied by the first warning, and is not a guarantee by the standard. Also `printf("---%d---\n", po2);` should be `printf("---%p---\n", po2);`

Comment: `*po2 = foo` -> `po2 = &foo`

Comment: Change this `*po2 = foo;` to that: `po2 = &foo;`

Comment: If you program in C you need a good understanding of pointers. I suggest you go searching and learning. Most people like to draw pictures with boxes and arrows - I know I do. So try searching for images of "C pointers", and read the associated articles. The investment in time will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i prepare to read through a relative book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You are using the incorrect format specifier within the string in the `printf()`. the `%d` is specifically for integers. For a pointer you should use `%p`.

   Looking at the warning you received you can determine this from this bit:  `format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *'` which basically means that the format specifier (the `%d`) indicates an `int` type variable but you have supplied a `char *` type.
2. When you say `*po2 = foo;` you are actually assigning the *value* of `foo` to whatever is *pointed at* by `po2`, instead of assigning the *address* of `foo` into `po2` *itself*.

   Firstly, when assigning an address to a pointer, do not use the `*`, so the first part becomes `po2 =`. Secondly, you want to allocate the address of `foo` rather than the value it holds, thus you should use the "address-of" operator, that is `&` so the entire line then becomes `po2 = &foo;`

   The reason your current code gives a segmentation fault is because, as mentioned your current code assigns the value of `foo`, to wherever `po2` is *pointing at*. Because the pointer has not been correctly initialized yet, it holds some indeterminate address (usually `NULL`) that is invalid. Thus when the PC tries to find this invalid address it is trying to find a memory location location that does not exist (e.g. location 0 or location 5 billion, etc). It cannot do this and so it results in a segmentation fault.

You seem to have misunderstood a little bit how pointers work. When you use `char *po2;`, this creates a variable that *holds an address*. This is just the same as creating any other type of variable, there is no other memory allocated other than the memory used to hold the address. Because a pointer defined like this is not initialized, it will contain an indeterminate address value. In some situations (but not all) this value will be `NULL`, or `0`, this is why your `printf` outputs `0` after it gives a warning.

If you would like to have the pointer `po2` point at the variable `foo` then you put the address of `foo` into the pointer. `po2` will hold the address of `foo` and `foo` will still hold `'D'`. The `'D'` is not magically moved to some other part of memory pointed to by `po2`, it stays right where it is. If you were to use the pointer to change the value of what it is pointing at, then the value in `foo` would be the value altered.

For example:

```
char *po2;   // A pointer variable that will hold an address of a char
char foo = 'D'; // A variable that will hold a char
po2 = foo;   // po2 contains a new copy of 'D', this is not what you wanted
po2 = &foo;  // po2 contains address of foo, this is right
*po2 = 'C';  // foo will now contain 'C'
*po2 = foo;  // same as using foo = foo
po2 = 'C';   // po2 contains 'C', this is not what you wanted
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. the reason why i used `%d` instead of `%p` is i thought the address must be integer (maybe larger as double) and the reason it should be used as `%p` should be the C language principle.

Comment: Ah...thanks again for your recommended articles, and they must bring me more in-depth understanding.

Comment: @puming you should choose the specifier based on data type, rather than size. In C, there are things of the same size but different types, so would usually be printed differently :)

Answer (score -1):

Problem is here:

```
*po2 = foo;
```

You need to assign address to pointer po2, not value. In this case you assigned pointer po2 value of variable foo. If you want to assign address do this:

```
po2 = &foo;
```

Comment: Downvoting because `*po2 = &foo;` and "In this case you assigned pointer po2 value of variable foo." are incorrect.